# Javascript (VueJS) Object with Array

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, vue.js

```
   {
  "data": {
    "id": 3,
    "name": "random",
    "email": "randon@yahoo",
    "created_at": "2017-02-06 18:16:06",
    "updated_at": "2017-02-06 18:16:06",
    "roles": [
      {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "ADMIN",
        "access": {
          "role4": true,
          "role3": true,
          "role2": true,
          "role1": true
        },
        "created_at": "-0001-11-30 00:00:00",
        "updated_at": "-0001-11-30 00:00:00"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

I am trying to access "access" and receive results true/false but it does not work

```
currentUser.roles[0].access['role1'];
```

Error: Cannot read property '0' of undefined

but

```
console.log(currentUser.roles[0].access['role1']); // returns true
```

and

```
currentUser.roles // gives me all the roles
```

The data is passed to the front-end with Laravel Transformer.

Note:Using VueJs and this is inside methods:

Comment: Isn't it data.roles[0].access['role1']?

Comment: no it's undefined

Comment: I mean... where does currentUser come from? I cannot find it in your object

Comment: this.currentUser = data
if I use this.currUser.id or data.id its the same

Comment: So in your case `console.log(currentUser.roles[0].access['role1']);` worked but `currentUser.roles[0].access['role1'];` not? Umm... I cannot go further without more information and context.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since I don't see whole code, I can assume.
First you have match data with

```
this.currentUser = data //data that you retrieve
```

and then access it:

```
this.currentUser.roles[0].access['role1']
```

Answer (score 0):

Within the `VueComponent` context, `data` attributes are spread into its `this` context. Therefore:

```
 this.roles[0].access['role1']
```

Comment: but first I need to refer to the currently logged in user. Thats why currentUser.